# FTP block issue on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ftp

for a long time i could access our ftp from explorer like open explorer and type ftp://mysite.com and put Uid & pass and click enter then ftp open where i can copy file delete file etc. last couple of days i could not access my ftp site from my office machine only but from other office machine ftp is accessible. my knowledge about blocking is zero. so how could i determine the reason why the ftp is block. if some one intentionally block my ftp access from my office pc then how could i be confirm. is there any way. how many way one could block my pc to access our ftp. also suggest how to unblock it please discuss in details.

Comment: Really this is off-topic here. Programming questions right?

Answer (score 0):

Try to verify the firewall settings...maybe something went wrong and now it's blocki

Answer (score 0):

try to allow FTP port (by default 21) on your windows 7 firewall.
your router may also block the access, so try also to allow FTP port in your router setting.